# Copy a binary file to instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

Using Heat how can I copy a binary file to the instance? For regular txt file (e.g. a text file called "new.txt"), I can use -

```
heat_template_version: 2015-10-15

description: Simple template

test:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      image: cirros
      flavor: m1.tiny
      personality: {"/opt/new.txt": {get_file: "/home/user/new.txt"}}
      networks:
        - network: private
```

But same thing does not work for binary files. In case of binary file, after the instance creation I can see that a file with same name as the binary file is created but the contents are different. The newly generated file in the instance is not a binary file. It is a regular file. The contents changed somehow.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Python heatclient with version number older than v0.2.9 had a bug where binary files were not handled correctly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-heatclient/+bug/1284501

Upgrading your python-heatclient package should resolve this.

Comment: My python-heatclient version is 1.0.0-1.